# After migrate from Live WordPress to Localhost get "not allowed to access page"

Tags: wordpress

I have migrated live WordPress to Localhost for testing purposes. I follow the recommended steps for this task.

Now the website is running locally with the following issues:

1. I only can see the old fashion of the theme, the default page (I use theme called jupiter).
2. When I try to open wp-admin page, it shows me “Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.” message.

I have done several attempts:

1. Add new user details in wp-user and wp-usermeta tables
2. Deactivate plugins
3. Remove .htaccess file from root doc

But all these attempts did not work for me.

Any help with 1 & 2?

Comment: What steps did you take to migrate it to your local machine? Did you change the URL's and paths in the database from old domain to localhost?

Comment: maybe the role has been changed from Admin to None.. Check the role adding some code in function.php.

Comment: @jrswgtr Yes, I replaced Live Site Url with Local Site URL in database in wp_options, wp_posts and wp-postmeta. I follow the steps from this page https://www.5balloons.info/migrate-setup-live-wordpress-site-localhost/.

Comment: Tejas Gajjar can you explain more what do you mean by role here. However, I have created new user and add thenew user details in wp-users and wp-usersmeta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I change the $table_prefix  value in wp-config.php to the new prefix. Then add a new user to _users and _usermeta tables with administrator privilege. This solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php version and update it to 7.0 minimum and also update your memory_limit, post_max_size, upload_max_size. Because jupiter theme has some minimum requirements to fulfill and work. You can check this in documentation of jupiter theme.

Comment: My php version is 7.1.33 and I have increased values upload_max_filesize , post_max_size and max_execution_time

Comment: are you now able to open wp-admin page?

Comment: No, I am not able, still having error "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

Comment: ok then try to update your wordpress using ftp. upload wp-admin, wp-includes folder and all other files except wp-config.php and wp-content folder. It will work

Comment: What do you mean here by update. Do you mean re-download the Live wordpress files/folders for my websites to localhost wordpress folder? by the way I use XAMPP for runningthe local server

Comment: yes exactly, download wordpress files and then change the folder i mentioned above.

Comment: I did exactly what you have told me but I got the same message Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.” .

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly what you have told me but I got the same message Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page @Hritik Pandey